# Size of topic in command line

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to know the size of a topic in the command line?

The topic I am dealing with should return 1920 values and I want to confirm that, without doing a `cout` in the code!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189188/size-of-topic-in-command-line/) by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rostopic doesn't support this directly. You might be able to hack it by doing something like:

```
rostopic echo -n1 /topic/array | wc -l # echo the array part of one message (-n1) into the word count program (wc) and count lines (-l)
```

This might be off by one or two depending on how rostopic formats the output; you might want to look at one or two examples before piping it into wc.

Or just add a check for the correct array size in your code, and a warning if the array is not the correct size.

The ROS message definition also allows for fixed-size arrays in messages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1